# Discord JS "send" is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I've been having an issue with Discord JavaScript that causes "send" to become undefined when you're trying to call "channels.get". Codes provided below!
(Code)

```
try{
    message.channels.get(`name`, `mod-logs`).send({embed: {
        "color" 4886754,
        "author": {
            "name": "Command Ran",
            "icon_url": message.author.avatarURL
         },
         "fields": [
             {
                "name": `Initiated by user: ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`,
                 "value": "**Command Status**: Successful :heavy_check_mark:\n**Mod Status**: Successful :heavy_check_mark:",
                 "inline": true
             },
             {
                 "name": `Uptime:`,
                 "value": `${client.uptime / 1000}`,
                 "inline" true
              }
          ]
```

(Console)

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
at Object.exports.run (C:\Users\Warriorfoox\Desktop\DiscordBot\Paralyss\commands\uptime.js:22:51)
at Client.client.on.message (C:\Users\Warriorfoox\Desktop\DiscordBot\Paralyss\index.js:21:19)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Client.emit (events.js:211:7)
at MessageCreateHandler.handle (C:\Users\Warriorfoox\Desktop\DiscordBot\Paralyss\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Warriorfoox\Desktop\DiscordBot\Paralyss\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Warriorfoox\Desktop\DiscordBot\Paralyss\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Warriorfoox\Desktop\DiscordBot\Paralyss\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
```

Comment: please post the code, not screenshots!

Comment: Fixed. Is it okay now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot read property 'send' of undefined in discord.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976677/cannot-read-property-send-of-undefined-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
message.channels.get(`name`, `mod-logs`)
```

is wrong. Try getting the guild and finding it.

```
message.member.guild.channels.find()
```

Comment: This did not solve the issue. More-or-less made it stop working. Nothing has printed to the Console.

Comment: Oh duh, supposed to be .find --fixed the post

Comment: Thanks! It's functional now. Really appreciated Saddy :3

Comment: Np, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `message.channels.get('name', 'CHANNEL NAME')`.

You can use `message.client.channels.get('CHANNEL ID')`, or to get it by using the channel name, `message.guild.channels.find('name', 'CHANNEL NAME')`.

If it is a channel in another guild, you can use something like
`client.user.guilds.get('GUILD ID').channels.find('name', 'CHANNEL NAME');`

You can find full documentation on this at [discord.js.org](http://discord.js.org)